# Expo camera in react native not saving to Media Library

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I get the error:

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'camera.takePicture Async')`

When running my app in react native following the Expo Camera docs.
My code is like this:

```
export default function App() {

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      const { status2 } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera or photos</Text>;
  }
}

function Cam() {

   const takePicture = async () => {
    const photo = await camera.takePictureAsync()
    MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri)
  }

  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={takePicture}
            style={{
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            bottom: 0,
            borderRadius: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}
          >
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={{transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }], color: 'white', textAlign: 'left'}}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Everything worked fine until I attempted to save a taken picture to my camera. I have saved images before similarly to this, so I have no clue what is different/wrong/would cause errors like this.

My full program can be found on [Snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/@theanton205/app_cam)

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#takepictureasync) you have to create the reference to the camera.

```
function Cam() {
   const cameraRef = useRef() // here

   const takePicture = async () => {
    const photo = await camera.current.takePictureAsync() // use it here
    MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri)
  }

  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type} rewf={cameraRef}> // add the reference to the existing camera component
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={takePicture}
            style={{
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            bottom: 0,
            borderRadius: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}
          >
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={{transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }], color: 'white', textAlign: 'left'}}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```